# Grails controller test - member variable not recognized

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit, intellij-idea

Grails (2.1.1., JUnit 4.1, IntelliJ) Controller test. Why isn't uc visible for testHandleLogin in the top snippet?

This one fails the assertion in testHandleLogin, because uc is null

```
@TestFor(UserController)
class UserControllerTests {

    UserController uc
    //def UserController uc > same result, fails 

    void setUp() {

        uc = new UserController()
    }

    void testHandleLogin() {

        assert uc
    }
```

This works, ie assertion succeeds

```
@TestFor(UserController)
class UserControllerTests {

    void setUp() {}

    void testHandleLogin() {

        def uc = new UserController()
        assert uc
    }
```

Comment: On a side note: Notice that you should always call super.setUp() as well.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, five minutes after asking the question I find the solution:

Adding "@Before" to the setUp() method does the trick.

Comment: In that case, you'll want to also add @Test to the test case `@Test void handleLogin()`. Then you won't be mixing junit version 3 style with junit 4.  You can also remove the word test from the beginning of each case that is annotated with @Test because it will no longer use reflection to identify test cases.